# What does かける mean in 人類の宇宙にかける夢はとどまるところを知らない?

Tags: meaning

Consider the following sentence.

> 人類の宇宙にかける夢はとどまるところを知らない。

- 人類 mankind
- 宇宙 universe
- かける ?
- 夢 dream
- とどまるところを知らない when it stops is unknown (lit. it keeps on happening)

As there are many meaning for かける, my translation below has not been completed yet.

> The dream of humankind かける in the universe never stops.

## Question

What does かける mean in this context?

Comment: You may think of this かける as the same かける as in "コートをハンガーにかける", only used figuratively here. "人類の宇宙にかける夢" is a noun phrase consisting of the relative clause "人類の宇宙にかける" and the head "夢", where the "夢" is the object of the verb in the relative clause かける :"人類の宇宙にかける夢" ⇒ "dreams (which) mankind hangs on outer space". (Though an alternative reading, where the "の" in the "人類の" is construed as a genitive, rather than subject, marker, may be possible.) If the meaning is not clear, the "hang" is used in the sense similar to "hang one's hope on something."

Comment: This かける means "hope". http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A4%A2%E3%82%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 懸ける, that is, the dream of mankind to lean on/speculate in/venture in the space.

Answer (score 2):

'かける' in the sentence is '翔る' which means 'to fly high and fast'. The Kanji '翔' means to fly in '飛翔 ひしょう'.

Comment: If it was 翔ける, it would have been 宇宙 を 翔ける.

Comment: @user4092 Do you mean [未来・宇宙に翔ける無限の可能性を示しているとのこと.](http://news.mynavi.jp/news/2013/07/10/318/) is wrong? I don't see any reason why you can't use 'に' in the sentence. Do you?

Comment: It means that you fly (through present time / stratosphere) towards future / the space. Likewise, it's not technically impossible to interpret 宇宙に翔ける as to fly (through stratosphere) towards the space. But I see it's referring to actual space industry rather than a rhetoric expression in public relations.